# how to display a string like "'*'"

Tags: python

Try to print string to yaml like  - `"'*'"` .

```
CORS = '\"\'*\'\"' .   
globals_res = {'API': {'Cors': {'AllowMethods': CORS, 
                                'AllowHeaders': CORS, 
                                'AllowOrigin': CORS}
}   
print(yaml.safe_dump(jl,default_flow_style=False))
```

result

```
API:  
    Cors:         
         AllowHeaders: ' "''*''" '  
         AllowMethods: ' "''*''" '  
         AllowOrigin: ' "''*''" '
```

must be

```
API:  
   Cors:  
        AllowMethods: "'*'" .   
        AllowHeaders: "'*'" .  
        AllowOrigin: "'*' .
```

Comment: probably easiest using triple quotes

Comment: `'*'` should be perfectly fine. That's a Python string containing one asterisk. `safe_dump` will translate that to the equivalent YAML string containing one asterisk. You should not need to worry about escaping at all.

Comment: triple quotes not work's

Comment: could you modify the question to include some markup/formatting to indicate the code, it's difficult to tell what's relevant without this

Comment: for SAM template I have string like - AllowMethods: "'*'"

Comment: @SamMason I try generate AWS SAM Template yaml file. This file has section - Globals:
    Api:
        Cors:
            AllowMethods: "'*'"
            AllowHeaders: "'*'"
            AllowOrigin: "'*'" Globals:
    and try -

Comment: @СергейБорисов posting multiline code into comments like that doesn't help — you need to update/edit the post.  I've done some changes, and have left your `.`'s at the end of the final set of code which don't look right.  I'd suggest modifying them if they're not supposed to be in the final file

Comment: @SamMason I try use - CORS = '\"\'*\'\"'  and CORS = ''' '"'*'"' '''

Comment: @СергейБорисов please use backticks (`\``) to indicate code, the help button has information about how to use Markdown format.  does https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/323 look similar to YAML you're trying to generate?

Comment: @SamMason yes, I try generate similar YAML

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to just use `"'*'"`

to show how to get this for other strings, I generated a dummy YAML document containing the required YAML output (`"'*'"`) by doing:

```
document = ''' "'*'" '''
```

then loading using `PyYAML` package:

```
import yaml
x = yaml.load(document)
```

which I can then display using:

```
print(repr(x))
```

which outputs the constant I need (`"'*'"`).  this can then be used to generate a valid file, via something like:

```
allow_all = "'*'"
cors = {
  "AllowMethods": allow_all,
  "AllowHeaders": allow_all,
  "AllowOrigin": allow_all,
}
apisettings = {"Globals": {"Api": {"Cors": cors}}}
print(yaml.dump(apisettings))
```

which gives me:

```
Globals:
  Api:
    Cors: {AllowHeaders: '''*''', AllowMethods: '''*''', AllowOrigin: '''*'''}
```

which is actually the same as you're after, but you'll need to read the YAML spec to see how to [escape scalars](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786942). you might reassure yourself by doing:

```
yaml.load("'''*'''")
```

and getting `"'*'"` back again.